# Samsung SmartThings washer and dryer unable to connect to the app

Tags: networking, samsung-smartthings, mobile-applications

For the past few weeks I've been unable to use my Samsung SmartThings washer and dryer via the app. I use the notification feature to keep track of completed loads and sometimes use the app to start the machines or delay their runs.

Ever since I switched to a Unifi Dream Machine to run the devices, I've been struggling to connect to them and use them remotely. Every time I run the set-up process, they will stay connected for a few hours at a time and then irreparably go offline. Only plugging them out and in again temporarily fixes the issue.

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

- Connecting the devices to a dedicated IoT VLAN (isolated Wi-Fi network)
- Punching the necessary holes in the firewall according to [this guide](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m-ghwm_1nR7T7JeI7ACe-U0883qj6i9WGKN1hYu-Ao8/edit#gid=0) (rules 2024, 2025)
- Resetting the devices' network settings [with the guide provided by Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00087882/#:%7E:text=Reset%20your%20washing%20machine,all%20it%20takes%20to%20reset.)
- Researching the Unifi forums and tweaking all settings that could affect connectivity negatively (disabling 5GHz Wi-Fi, disabling U-APSD, enabling/disabling router features that help or hinder connectivity
- Giving the devices static IP addresses
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the iPhone app, as well as running the app on a different Apple device to see if it had to do with the iPhone itself
- Deleting my Samsung account
- Unplugging each of the devices manually and re-plugging them (which only fixes the connectivity issue temporarily)

Nothing so far has worked. I plan to contact Samsung support soon but I wonder if anyone else has run into this before and whether they've been able to solve it. It's a minor issue as the devices still work manually but frustrating nonetheless as it's part of the reason why I bought these devices in particular.

Here are the model names:

- Washer: Samsung WW90T636ALH Autodose
- Dryer: Samsung DV90T5240AW
- SmartThings iOS App: 1.6.70-549
- UDM: Dream Machine (EU Version), Unifi OS 1.10.0, Unifi Network 6.4.54
- iPhone XS Max, running iOS 15.

Comment: sounds like an issue with UniFi Dream Machine

Comment: Did you solve this out of interest? Series 6 washer and dryer, dream machine Pro with unifi AP's. I'm having a similar issue. To fix it short term I have to unplug the washing machine/dryer off while on and they work again for a while.

Comment: related: https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Smart-Home-Support/Washer-and-Dryer-w-SMART-Home-connect-only-for-a-minute-then/td-p/65450

Comment: I highly recommend you send this to the SmartThings forum or open a support ticket. You will get more specific and targeted advice there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but the devices recently started working as expected. If others run into the same issue, I suggest updating your UDM (or whatever router you use) to the latest software version (I'm running 7.0.23) and making sure the washer/dryer is also up to date. Before the issue resolved itself, I took to unplugging the device and plugging it back in whenever it'd stop connecting, in order to force a soft reset.

Resetting the network settings of the machine [(see here for instructions)](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00087882/) and then connecting it to SmartThings again may also help.

These are my Wi-Fi network settings:

[image]